# apply rewrite tactic to sub-expression

Tags: coq, ltac

How can I apply `rewrite ->` targetting only a sub-expression? For example, consider this theorem:

```
Parameter add : nat -> nat -> nat.
Axiom comm : forall a b, add a b = add b a.

Theorem t1 : forall a b : nat,
(add (add a b) (add a (add a b))) =
(add (add a b) (add a (add b a))).
```

Intuitively, it requires commuting only one `(add a b)` sub-expression, but if I do  `rewrite -> (comm a b)`, it rewrites all the occurrences. How can I target a particular sub-expression?

Answer (score 3):

This is a case where the ssreflect matching facilities will usually be more convenient than "`at`" [I'd dare to say sub-term rewrites are often a cause of people switching to ssreflect's rewrite]. In particular:

- `rewrite {pos}[pat]lemma` will select occurrences `pos` of pattern `pat` to rewrite,
- `pat` can be a [contextual pattern](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/proof-engine/ssreflect-proof-language.html#contextual-patterns) that may allow you improve the robustness of your scripts.

Answer (score 2):

You can target a specific occurrence with the `rewrite` tactic using the suffix `at N`. Occurrences are numbered from 1 in left-to-right order. You can rewrite multiple occurrencess by separating their indices with spaces. You need `Require Import Setoid`. The `at` suffix is also available with some other tactics that target occurrences of a term, including many tactics that perform conversions (`change`, `unfold`, `fold`, etc.), `set`, `destruct`, etc.

```
intros.
rewrite -> (comm a b) at 2.
rewrite -> (comm _ _).
reflexivity.
```

There are other possible approaches, especially if all you need is to apply equalities. The `congruence` tactic can find what to rewrite and apply symmetry and transitivity on its own, but you need to prime it by adding all equivalences to the context (in the form of universally-quantified equalities), it won't query hint databases.

```
assert (Comm := comm).
congruence.
```

To get more automation, `Hint Rewrite` creates a database of theorems which the tactic `autorewrite` will try applying. For more advanced automation, look up [generalized rewriting](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/addendum/generalized-rewriting.html) with setoids, which I'm not sufficiently familiar with to expound on.

Comment: In cases like this one, we can target the right subexpression by choosing the arguments of `comm`: `intros a b. rewrite (comm b a). reflexivity.`